# Current focused button after button down event in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I tried to use `qApp->focusWidget()`. This gives me the information about the current item that has the focus.

For example:

`-->QPushButton(0xcdacc0, name = "pushButton")`

With this information, the same Rune-in function?

I want to use the address `0xcdacc0`

Comment: I have no clue whatsoever what you are trying to ask. Please edit your question with much more explanation in what you are trying to to and what you have tried to achieve that.

Comment: @Bowdzone i want using 0xcdacc0 adress pointer

Comment: Why do you a want to use an absolute address pointer? What are you expecting to achieve by that!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bowdzone already mentioned, it would really help if you add more information to your question and explain what is that you want to achieve.

What I guess that you want to do is upon a signal being sent, you want to know which object sent the signal and you want to do something with that object. If that is indeed the case, then you could either use the method that you mentioned or you use the `sender` method.

In the example below I have a simple dialog with a checkbox and a push button. They are both connected to the same slot. When the slot is called, it determines what type of object called it and then casts them to the corresponding type and performs an action with them. Note that I use two different methods to determine the type, one using qt `QMetaObject` and the other using a `dynamic_cast`, and also the two different methods to determine who sent the signal (`sender` and `focusWidget` as mentioned above). This is simply to show that [TIMTOWTDI](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/TIMTOWTDI) (even if this is not perl).

This is simply dummy code to show the principle, your implementation will then depend on what you want to do.

**dialog.h**

```
#ifndef MYDIALOG_H
#define MYDIALOG_H

#include "ui_dialog.h"

class Dialog: public QDialog, public Ui::Dialog
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);


public slots:

  void handleAction();

};


#endif
```

**dialog.cc**

```
#include "dialog.h"

#include <QtCore>

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent)
{
  setupUi(this);
  connect(pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(handleAction()) );
  connect(checkBox,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(handleAction()) );
}

void Dialog::handleAction()
{
  QWidget *widget = QApplication::focusWidget();

  if( strcmp( widget->metaObject()->className(), "QPushButton") == 0 ) {
    qDebug() << "this comes from a QPushButton, let me print the text on the button";
    QPushButton *button = static_cast<QPushButton*>(widget);
    qDebug() << button->text();

  } else if ( dynamic_cast<QCheckBox*>(widget) ) {
    qDebug() << "this comes from a QCheckBox, let me print its check status";
    QCheckBox *check = static_cast<QCheckBox*>(widget);
    qDebug() << check->isChecked();
  }

  QObject *object = sender();

  if( strcmp( object->metaObject()->className(), "QPushButton") == 0 ) {
    qDebug() << "this comes from a QPushButton, let me print the text on the button";
    QPushButton *button = static_cast<QPushButton*>(object);
    qDebug() << button->text();

  } else if ( dynamic_cast<QCheckBox*>(object) ) {
    qDebug() << "this comes from a QCheckBox, let me print its check status";
    QCheckBox *check = static_cast<QCheckBox*>(object);
    qDebug() << check->isChecked();
  }

}
```

Let me know if this helps.